# windows mapped folder access

Tags: 12.04, networking, mount, samba, file-sharing

I have successfully mapped a a shared folder in windows to Ubuntu. But I can't save anything in the folder from Ubuntu.  I can browse and open and all but I can't save anything to the folder or create any files in that folder.  I have given full read/write access to the folder from windows. here is my fstab entry if its help. please let me know how to get this work.
//192.168.2.3/miracle /media /miracle cifs username=admin, password=password123, iocharset=utf8, sec=ntlm   0    0
Thanks in advance for looking into this

Comment: Please provide the text of any error messages you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for all the info and assistance.  The following worked for me.

//192.168.2.3/miracle /media/miracle cifs username=admin,password=Passwrd123,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777      0      0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have too many fields.

The first field is the Windows share name. For you that would be //192.168.2.3/miracle. The second field is the mapped directory on the Linux side. For you it's /media. That gives you an extra field called /miracle before you give the FS type. Maybe there's a space in the share name on the Windows side. If so, use \040 instead of a space. This link basically has all the information that you're looking for.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Good luck.